# How to extract values at specific position from a list when data frame columns consist of lists

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two columns in pandas data frame and each row in the two columns has a list of values.
First, I want to locate a certain value from a list in one column and extract a corresponding value at the same position from the list in the other column. For example, my data looks like this:

```
    Address               Value
[abcd, jkel, swkg]     [30, 25, 87]
[eszl, pqks, jkel]     [21, 35, 42]
[jkel, sqzg]           [11, 34]
```

I want to extract a corresponding value from the value list when address is "jkel". For example, the list in the first row of the address column has "jkel" at the second position in the list. The corresponding value of this address will be the second item in the value list, which is 25. Eventually, I'd like to create a new data frame that looks like this.

```
     Address               Value
      jkel                  25
      jkel                  42
      jkel                  11
```

I tried to locate all the rows whose address column contains "jekl" and extract the relevant values using the index() function. But unfortunately, I couldn't figure out the whole thing.

```
df = df[df["Address"].str.contains("jekl")]

new_value = []
for row in df:
  idx = df['Address"].index("jekl")
  a = df['Value'][idx]
```

Could anyone please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try exploding the data and query:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Address': df['Address'].explode().
              'Value': df['Value'].explode()
             }).query('Value=="jkel"')
```